# Error while running integration test with Prisma Migrate

Tags: postgresql, testing, prisma

For migration management, I've decided to use `Prisma Migrate` instead of `node-pg-migrate` (PostgreSQL). I followed the instructions in [this](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/application-lifecycle/add-prisma-migrate-to-a-project) link and everything works fine. However, the main challenge is that my integration tests fail when trying to run migrations on the test database (not the develop database). How can I override the configurations of my test database?

In `node-pg-migrate` I could simply provide configurations before running the integration test:

```
import migrationRunner from 'node-pg-migrate';

// --- Integration test setup:
beforeAll(async () => {
  await migrationRunner({
    migrationsTable: dbConfig['migrations-table'],
    dir: dbConfig['migrations-dir'],
    schema: dbConfig.schema,
    databaseUrl: databaseURL,
    // --- other configs
  });
}, config.get('test').timeout);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the entire connection string directly in your test setup [as follows](https://github.com/ryands17/fastify-prisma/blob/main/prisma/prisma-test-environment.js#L23-L25). Prisma reads the DB string from environment variables so overriding in the following manner will work fine.

Comment: Nice, however, I could not override the environment variable for the tests. I wanted to have a separate configuration of DATABASE_URL for each test.

Comment: It should be possible it in the `beforeEach` block for the test by overriding `process.env` for that variable.